# Read Sql Table using Connectorx?

Tags: python, sql-server, mysql-connector, connector, mysql-connector-python

I am reading sql tables using connectorX library and saving as csv but facing weird error
The code is

```
import connectorx as cx

MYSQL_READER_HOST = cfg.sql['host']
MYSQL_READER_USERNAME = cfg.sql['user']
MYSQL_READER_PASSWORD = cfg.sql['passwd']
MYSQL_DB_NAME = cfg.sql['db']

tables = ['table1','table2']
for table in tables:               #line 52 of my code
    print(f'\t => \t Storing {table}')
    query = "select /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(100000000) */ * from "+ table+";"
    
    table = cx.read_sql(f'mysql://{MYSQL_READER_USERNAME}:{MYSQL_READER_PASSWORD}@{MYSQL_READER_HOST}/{MYSQL_DB_NAME}' ,query,partition_num=10)
    table.to_csv(os.path.join(store_dir, table + '.csv'), index=False)
```

the error I am facing

```
Fatal Python error: none_dealloc: deallocating None
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00003d60 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\LunchON\Desktop\download_script\util_scripts\data_download_connector_x.py", line 52 in <module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try version >=`0.2.4-alpha.4`? This issue should has been fixed https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/issues/201

Comment: pip install connectorx==0.2.4a6